# Cast shadow of transparent plane in URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, shadow

I need the shadows of this plane with a custom shader made in shader graph to cast shadow with the same patern. I realy don't know what i can do or did wrong.

Thanks in advance !

[image: Shadow who doesn't work]

Comment: Are you using the basic Unlit Master node? Make sure it's set to opaque and set the alpha clip threshold to something like 0.5

Comment: No i've used the unit graph so that i can use shader graph

Comment: That's fine, and I mean the final node within the Shader Graph, it should be Unlit Master.

Comment: so no idea why the light pass through the transparent parts ? or how i can make it pass ?

Comment: Can you post an image of what your custom shader graph looks like?

Comment: yes here : https://imgur.com/JdxqRZg

Comment: Yep, so like I said either change surface to Opaque or set AlphaClipThreshold to 0.5

Comment: Thank you so mutch i feel so dumb thanks its working pefectly

Comment: maybe you could post your response here so that i can set it to be the solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within ShaderGraph go to the **Unlit Master** node.

From here you can either:

1. Set **AlphaClipThreshold** to 0.5
2. Press on the little cog and change the **Surface** to **Opaque**