# In Unity URP, AlphaTest Shader's shadows are displayed the same

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, shadow, urp

I am a developer who has just started programming shaders.

I'm making a shader that renders shadows while using alphatest in a Unity URP environment.

However, as shown in the following figure, there is a problem that the shadows are rendered the same even though they are different objects.

[figure1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7rip.png)

[figure2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgI7w.png)

I checked in the Frame Debugger that the texture doesn't change when creating the Shadowmap.

[frame debugger 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rv7jS.png)

[frame debugger 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMQky.png)

The project environment is as follows:

Unity version: 2019.4.21

URP version: 7.5.3

Project repository: https://github.com/lklab/UnityURPAlphaTestShadow

My shader code: https://github.com/lklab/UnityURPAlphaTestShadow/blob/master/Assets/Shaders/URPAlphaTestUnlitShadow.shader

I would be very grateful if you could help.

※ I'm already using Opaque and AlphaTest (AlphaClip).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast shadow of transparent plane in URP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65693026/cast-shadow-of-transparent-plane-in-urp)

Comment: @Iggy, I'm already using Opaque and AlphaTest (AlphaClip). Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

The problem was due to the SRP batcher.

I solved it by writing the same CBUFFER for all passes in the shader like this:

```
TEXTURE2D(_MainTex);
TEXTURE2D(_LightTex);
SAMPLER(sampler_MainTex);
SAMPLER(sampler_LightTex);

CBUFFER_START(UnityPerMaterial)
half4 _MainTex_ST;
half4 _LightTex_ST;
CBUFFER_END
```

I have also updated the Project repository.